# error shows while using type casting for input in python3

Tags: python-3.x, function, input, typeerror, args

I am trying to take multiple numbers as input and use those numbers as parameters as *args in function,but python interpreter shows it is a s error.I tried in different type and it works well.But i want to know the difference between them.?

```
#numbers = [int(x) for x in input("Enter multiple value: ").split(",")] # gives no error
numbers=int(input()).split(",") #Giving error

def add(*numbers):
    sum=0
    for number in numbers:
        sum=sum+number
    print(sum)


print(add(*numbers))
```

Comment: `int(input()).split(",")` does not work. Do you think int has a `split` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

int(input()).split(",") -> of course this will return error.
The split() method splits a string into a list. Your code implies converting input into int type and split the integer.

numbers = [int(x) for x in input("Enter multiple value: ").split(",")]
this will not throw an error as you are creating a list of integers by iterating through list generated by split.